# Why wasn't log message written my log file when running Junit tests?

Tags: java, logging, junit, log4j, slf4j

I have a class Store which contains statements like "log.info(...)". I can see the log messages with the log file created when running the program. However, when I run JUnit tests, the log file won't be created, but I still want to see log messages. The logger is:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

And my log4j properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, STDOUT, file

log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=mylogs.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

The questions is, how to also create the log file and log messages when running my Junit tests?

Edit:

Part of the test log property:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, Console
log4j.logger.play=DEBUG
log4j.appender.Console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p ~ %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=testlog.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: What kind of project is this, eg maven, gradle, basic eclipse/intellij java project etc? And do you have a `log4j.properties` in your test classpath?

Comment: @Morfic, it's a maven project in Eclipse. Yes, I have a log4j.properties under src/test/resources folder.

Comment: You can use it to customize the logging configuration for your tests? What does it look like, perhaps it only has a console appender defined?

Comment: @Morfic, please see the log file under src/test/resources.

Answer (score 0):

According to that configuration, you'd probably expect to have a `testlog.log` file in the root of your project.

Nonetheless, the `file` appender is not referenced so the messages will only be logged using the `Console` appender. However, your `rootLogger` is set to `ERROR` level so messages *below* this level, such as `DEBUG`, `INFO` or `WARN` will be discarded.

You can either change your `rootLogger` configuration, from which all non-explicitly configured loggers inherit, just like in your other `log4j.properties`, or define a logger for your package, setting it to `DEBUG` (or whatever level you want) and use both the appends: `log4j.logger.my.package.here=DEBUG, Console, file`.

Further reading resources:
   - [log4j v1.2 into](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)
   - [log4j 1.2 configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/configuration.html)

**P.S.**: Please note that sometimes Eclipse has issues with the file-system changes and does not automatically update the project files. If that happens. after running your test, try right clicking your project in the `Navigator` view, and selecting refresh, then scroll to the end where your pom is. Alternatively open the file explorer of your choice, go to your project root on the disk and you should see the `testlog.log` file.